# Twitter API v2のBatch Complicateの使い方がわからない

Tags: twitter

### 困っていること

Twitter API v2のBatch Complicateで正しくJobを作成して、ファイルをアップロードしても、空のファイルが返ってきてしまいます。

期待しているファイルの中身

```js
{"id":"155230xxxx","action":"delete","created_at":"2022-07-27T14:32:54.835Z","reason":"suspended"}
{"id":"155221xxxx","action":"delete","created_at":"2022-07-27T09:08:31.172Z","reason":"protected"}
{"id":"155214xxxx","action":"delete","created_at":"2022-07-27T04:10:57.052Z","reason":"suspended"}
{"id":"155229xxxx","action":"delete","created_at":"2022-07-27T13:58:52.876Z","reason":"protected"}
{"id":"155227xxxx","action":"delete","created_at":"2022-07-27T12:56:18.336Z","redacted_at":"2022-07-27T13:55:51.964Z","reason":"deactivated"}
```

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/compliance/batch-compliance/introduction

### やったこと

1. `Job`の作成
2. 自分のツイートのIDを4つファイルに記載して`upload_url`にアップロード
3. Jobのstateが`complete`になるのを確認
4. 先ほど記載した4つのIDのツイートを削除
5. `download_url`でファイルをダウンロード(なぜかこのファイルが空ファイル)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

やりかたはあっていたはずなのですが、うまくいかずデータを別のものにしたらうまくいきました。
https://qiita.com/39ff/items/7fbd7850360e4cedd9dd